# Disposable Request-scoped object

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring.net

I need to properly `Dispose` of an object instantiated at `request`-level scope in my MVC 5 application.

I have declared the object as follows:

```
<object id="dataContext" singleton="false" scope="request" type="MyDisposableObject, MyAssembly" factory-object="dataContextFactory" factory-method="Build" destroy-method="Dispose" ></object>

<object id="dataContextFactory" scope="application" type="MyFactoryClass, MyAssembly"/>
```

Code for the DataContextFactory is the following (there is little masking in names)

```
public class DataContextFactory: DbConfiguration
{

    public IDisposable Build()
    {
        return new Wrapper();
    }

    private class Wrapper : MyDisposableObject //: DbContext
    {
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing); //BREAKPOINT HERE
        }

        public new void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose(); //BREAKPOINT HERE
        }
    }
}
```

This experiment shows me, by placing a breakpoint on the Dispose method, that when I end page request the object (which is ultimately an EF6 `DbContext`) is not disposed of.

I have read [SPRNET-318](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPRNET-318) but it's kinda ambiguous to me. The bug title is "IDisposable singletons with request or session scopr are not disposed of", which matches my case; however the [correlated forum topic](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?453-Dispose-not-implemented-for-request-session-singletons) says about calling `WebApplicationContext.Dispose`, which is **not** my case because I never dispose of the context when the request ends.

Am I missing something on disposing of object at request/session level?

Comment: Are you using a `using {}` block or calling `Dispose()`.  If you are doing neither then no one can say exactly when `Dispose()`  will be called and therefore hit your breakpoint

Comment: No. I expect Spring to dispose of the object when the request ends. I tried to add a RequestCompleted event to Global.asax to explicitly get and dispose of the object, but this has a drawback: if I never instantiated the object in my request (e.g. it's a CSS request) it will instantiate and dispose of the object